# Bluetooth scanner reconnect android

Tags: android, bluetooth, intermec

I have a Samsung Galaxy Xcover 4, and a scanner (Intermec SR61).
The Samsung Galaxy XCover 4 is running an application 24/7, and never goes to sleep.

The Intermec SR61 is connected to this phone, and when scanning barcode, the application reads the barcode and handle the data.

After 24 hours, the Intermec SR61 loses connectivity to the phone.
It won't reconnect. I have to reconnect it through the application (disable/enable).

Why does this happen, and what can I do to make sure that doesn't happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created something similar and some phones connected to some scanners will do that. It is either a Bluetooth bug, a phone bug or a hardware thing.

There is not much you can do about it, I am afraid. Possibly you can change some settings in the scanner (sleep mode or something).

What I did to fix it, was to create a background process that keeps an eye on the connection and re-connects if it is gone. That process even goes so far to switch the Bluetooth adapter off and on again (because of problems on a certain phone).

Comment: Thank you Bart. It's a great suggestion for solving it.